# Warning C4640 in ATL Macro END_CONNECTION_POINT_MAP

Tags: c++, com, visual-studio-2015, atl

I am getting the warning

```
warning C4640: '_entries': construction of local static object is not thread-safe
```

from the ATL macro END_CONNECTION_POINT_MAP, for example

```
BEGIN_CONNECTION_POINT_MAP(CMBusInclinometerTemChannel)
  CONNECTION_POINT_ENTRY(__uuidof(IChannelEvents))
END_CONNECTION_POINT_MAP()
```

in a C++ ATL/COM project.

I think that this has started happening since installing Visual Studio 2015 update 2.

Does anybody have a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought it might be a new warning, but no - [it was earlier just turned off by default](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4f5c8560%28v=vs.140%29.aspx). I suppose it is a long standing "problem", however it might be not so easy to convert it to a real bug (if at all possible and has side effects).

The problem is about the map of connection points using static local variable `_entries` internally, which is initialized on first use in a thread-unsafe manner. It is however an initialization of a pointer with fixed values the pointer refers to. The problem might possibly be that thread #1 treats map as initialized while thread #2 is just in the middle of initialization. Pretty rare condition, no wonder there has been no complaints so far.

Solution might be in surrounding the static variable initialization with global critical section lock, such as

```
ATLASSERT(_pAtlModule);
CComCritSecLock<CComCriticalSection> Lock(_pAtlModule->m_csStaticDataInitAndTypeInfo);
static ...
```

in the map macros, and suppression of the warning using `#pragma`. This should be a fix in ATL headers code (atlcom.h).

Comment: Thanks @roman-r, I have disabled it with #pragma warning( disable : 4640 ) in stdafx.h. For some reason, it only worked for header files included directly in stdafx.h, but that's another problem.

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2539759/c4640-warning-cannot-be-disabled